# Function lateral flatten in snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, lateral

I need to un-parse JSON with lateral flatten. But I would like to have 2 values - one for club and one for free delivery, for club I am ok, but I can not get also free delivery
This is code I have

```
select  LPAD(PURCHASE_ID,10, '0')as PURCHASE_ID, DELIVERY_ID, PARTNER_ID,HAS_LABEL_FDEL, f3.value:commonLabels[0]::varchar as CLUB --,ORDER_ID as ue
from (select distinct PURCHASE_ID, DELIVERY_ID, PARTNER_ID,HAS_LABEL_FDEL, PARSE_JSON(PR_TRANSPORT) as PR_TRANSPORT from "DWHM_MALLGROUP"."SRC_ORACLEIWP"."PURCHASE_ANALYSIS_RULES" 
   ) as PAR,
lateral flatten(input => PAR.PR_TRANSPORT) f3
where PR_TRANSPORT is not null 
and f3.value:type='CLUB' ---????or f3.value:type='FREE_DELIVERY'
```

and here is parse  JSON looks like this for free delivery, which i would like to have :

> [{"ruleId":244419,"type":"FREE_DELIVERY"},{"ruleId":9942304,"type":"FREE_DELIVERY"}]
> This is how it looks for club :
> [{"commonLabels":["CZ_B2B_CLUB"],"ruleId":20228738,"type":"CLUB"}]

So one field for CLUBS, one for Free delivery

Comment: Please edit the question, add how the input looks, and how the output should look like

Comment: You mention club, but the data has no mention of club.  In to assist with this, I'd need full details of the data and the expected output.

Comment: Whole format looks like this : - here is data for club [{"commonLabels":["MALL_VIP_CLUB"],"ruleId":1961780,"type":"CLUB"}] , here are data for Free delivery : {"ruleId":244419,"type":"FREE_DELIVERY"},{"ruleId":9942304,"type":"FREE_DELIVERY"}] Expected OUTPUT should be : ID, club - if yes, Free delivery - if yes. Club, or free delivery is not with each order